# How to generate a list of all Word documents and their templates?

Tags: templates, microsoft-word-365

I would like to generate a list of all the Word documents on my laptop along with the templates that each uses. Is there a way to produce such a list? If not, how about getting a list of all my Word documents that use a specified template? This desire comes in part because I want to delete templates that I don't use. I am using Microsoft 365.

Comment: You can certainly do this using VBA, but it will require some VBA knowledge. Google for VBA scripts to walk through all subfolders, open each word document, and list the name plus the attached template. It will be slow, though.

Comment: Thanks, @Paul! I only have a little VBA skills, but I will search, and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub listDocs()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String

        'change folder name as needed
    HostFolder = "C:\users\myname"

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    getDocs FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub

Sub getDocs(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder As Object
    
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        Debug.Print SubFolder
        getDocs SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        If File.Type = "Microsoft Word Document" Then
            
            Documents.Open FileName:=File.Path, ReadOnly:=True
            Debug.Print File.Path, Documents(File.Name).AttachedTemplate
            Documents(File.Name).Close
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645347/loop-through-all-subfolders-using-vba. It will print every folder, and every Word file with its template name.

Note that it will take a long time, as it needs to open every single Word file on you

Comment: Thanks for the script. I changed the folder name to mine and ran it in Word, which I ran as administrator. I got this error:

Run-time error '70':
Permission denied

at the line:
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders

My VBA skills are minimal. Do you have a sense about what might be wrong?

Comment: Strange. What do you get in the immediate window, before it stops? You may need to add a `debug.print Folder` statement just before the For Each line to see what is happening.

Comment: Also, please make sure you are running the first macro (`listdocs`), not the second one; otherwise the folder will be undefined.

Comment: @libcub, any luck?